# Convert output of xsl to a url upon conditions

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm very much a novice at the moment, however I have used xsl to format an xml feed to out put into html for my site.  However, I would like to go a step further by also converting some of the output text to an html link.

Are there any tutorials available that could help?

To give a bit better context, the output is a football league table, that I would like to make the teams names automatically link to a url.  So if name = 'Portsmouth' then I would want Portsmouth to become a link I would determine.  How do I format the table below to do this for all the potentially different team names?

```
<xsl:for-each select="team">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="position"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="played"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="won"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="drawn"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="lost"/></td>  
<td><xsl:value-of select="for"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="against"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="goalDifference"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="points"/></td>

</tr>
```

`

Comment: If my answer helped you out, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally output a tags you can do the following.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//team"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="team">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="position"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name='Portsmouth'">
          <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('someurl.com?name=',name)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </a>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="played"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="won"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="drawn"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="lost"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="for"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="against"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="goalDifference"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="points"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Use apply-templates instead of a foreach loop.

If one of the teams is Portsmouth, the output would be

```
<td><a href="someurl.com?name=Portsmouth"/></td>
```

If you want each team to have a url then simply remove the choose statement and leave

```
  <td>
           <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('someurl.com?name=',name)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </a>
    </td>
```